# SONAR + R# analysis integration for MSBuild projects

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, continuous-integration, resharper

I have a problem to integrate SONAR and resharper output.
Here is the process I have :

With JENKINS and SONAR integration (sonar-scanner for ms build), I do not want to use roslyn analysis output but I would like to use R# (resharper) analysis. What I do is :

- I run resharper command line tool to analysis a solution.

  "E:\Jenkins\tools\JetBrains.ReSharper.CommandLineTools.2018.2.3\InspectCode" "E:\Jenkins\workspace\TPStrings\TPStrings.sln" --project=TPStrings --swea -s=INFO -o="E:\Jenkins\workspace\TPStrings\TPStrings.ReSharperReport.xml"
- Convert R# output into sonar output using dotnet-reqube.exe which turns R# output to JSON sonar output.
- Start SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe and reference my previous JSON sonar output using externalIssuesReportPaths parameter
- Run my build
- Delete the roslyn files from MSBUILd analysis so that there are not taken into account by sonar.
- End SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe : SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe end

Here is the output I get :

[Empty project issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nUQG.png)

but R# analysis errors are present :

[R# imported rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbQaM.png)

Why the project summary not well created with externalIssuesReportPaths?

I am expected to get something like :

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMn77.png)

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Any errors in the SonarQube logs?

Comment: I have found a solution yesterday, running in debug mode Sonar was looking for the sonar analysis files but I have erased after the build. It looks like Sonar needs these file to correctly imported and update a project. To do so I created a empty json file and now it works.